# Can we use constructor and destructor instead of setup and teardown?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

setup() and teardown() do the same thing as constructor and destructor does.
If no how are they differ?
if yes then why can't we use constructor and destructor in their place.

Comment: It explains in the [documentation](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/cppunit_cookbook.html) that these functions _call_ the constructor of whatever you're trying to test...

Answer (score 3):

SetUp and tearDown can't be replaced by constructor and destructor because they are internally protected against exceptions thrown by assertion macros. So you can add an assertion macro into setUp or tearDown but you can't do that in the destructor and would have some problems in the constructor.

Then cppunit is inspired by Junit which implements the same concept. And then there is the possibility to replace the setUp and tearDown inside a fixture with another setUp/tearDown method.